# How do I use command arguments with Cmnd_Alias in sudoers?

Tags: sudo

How do I specify command arguments in sudoers? As a background, `aws` command is actually a gateway to a whole bunch of sub-systems and I want to restrict the user to only run `aws s3 cp ...any other args...`

When I try the following in `/etc/sudoers`

```
Cmnd_Alias AWSS3_CMD = /usr/local/bin/aws s3 cp, /usr/local/aws/bin/aws s3 cp
gbt1 ALL=(gbt-ops) NOPASSWD: AWSS3_CMD
```

The shell unfortunately prompts for password

```
$ sudo -u gbt-ops aws s3 cp helloworld s3://my-bucket/hw.1
gbt-ops's password:
```

If I remove the command args in Cmnd_Alias, then it flows as desired (without password prompt), but the authorization are way too broad. *So, what is the right way of restricting to only certain types of command invocations*.

```
Cmnd_Alias AWSS3_CMD = /usr/local/bin/aws, /usr/local/aws/bin/aws
```

Then

```
$ sudo -u gbt-ops aws s3 cp helloworld s3://my-bucket/hw.1
...happy
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why do you have /usr/local/bin/aws, /usr/local/aws/bin/aws? I mean you repeated the command two times in the same line?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You haven't used any wildcards, but have provided two arguments. Therefore `sudo` looks for commands exactly as written (excepting path-lookup) (from [`man 5 sudoers`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/sudoers.5)):

```
 If a Cmnd has associated command line arguments, then the arguments in
 the Cmnd must match exactly those given by the user on the command line
 (or match the wildcards if there are any).
```

Try something like:

```
Cmnd_Alias AWSS3_CMD = /usr/local/bin/aws s3 cp *, /usr/local/aws/bin/aws s3 cp *
```

Note that:

```
 Wildcards in command line arguments should be used with care.  Because
 command line arguments are matched as a single, concatenated string, a
 wildcard such as ‘?’ or ‘*’ can match multiple words.
```

So, only one wildcard is needed per command.

Comment: Note that sudo doesn't properly respect separation of arguments which can be used for exploits in some cases, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/279142/43920. So instead of specifying `/usr/local/bin/aws s3 cp` in sudoers, it is safer to replace that with a script (only writable by root).

Answer (score 12):

The same as @muru, but for those who like full working example:

```
# Cmnd alias specification
Cmnd_Alias ECHO_CMD=/bin/echo A *,/bin/echo B *

# Make USER run specific commands on given HOSTNAME
# USER_NAME 

#userx
userx ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/cmd1,/sbin/cmd2,ECHO_CMD
```

While `/sbin/cmd1`,`/sbin/cmd2` can be any other commands.

The purpose of `ECHO_CMD` is to present that `sudo echo X A` will ask for passphrase, while `sudo echo A X` not, and to allow you to gain confidence through such simple experiment.

(It was assumed that echo sits in `/bin/echo`, to check where it is on your system try `whereis echo`)

Comment: Yes, there is `/bin/echo` binary, but most shells also have built-in function `echo` which will be used instead of this binary if you don't provide full path.

Answer (score 1):

you can use regexp in sudoers too.

this will allow `/usr/bin/apt update upgrade and auto-remove` to be run without password but if you specify a .deb name or `apt install` it will still prompt for password.

```
Cmnd_Alias UPDATES = /usr/bin/apt (update|upgrade|auto-remove)
%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: UPDATES
%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Comment: Important caveat: this requires at least sudo 1.9.10, so taking Ubuntu for example, 20.04 and 22.04 are out.

Comment: @muru, wow even the latest LTS haven't get this feature yet. This would save a lot of repetitive configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but lets say that this is `cat` instead of `echo` and there is a file `C` that a user doesn't have access to. You add the user to sudoers which allows:

```
# Cmnd alias specification
Cmnd_Alias ECHO_CMD=cat A *,cat B *
```

I would then have access to file C by running:

```
sudo echo A C
```

since C follows the wildcard syntax properly. I think this is a good example of bad security when using wildcards in sudo commands. I would be very careful with this usage and account for any possible variation the wildcard could produce!