# Specify command with quoted arguments in sudoers?

Tags: sudo, arguments

#### The General Case

I'm trying to enable a user to run a sudo command (with arguments) without a password. I can get the `NOPASSWD` directive to work, but only when the arguments don't contain quotation marks.

For example, this works:

```
# /etc/sudoers.d/sample
%sudo   ALL=(ALL)  NOPASSWD: /bin/echo foo

$ sudo echo foo
foo
```

But this doesn't, because quotation marks are interpreted literally:

```
# /etc/sudoers.d/sample
%sudo   ALL=(ALL)  NOPASSWD: /bin/echo "foo"

$ sudo echo "foo"
[sudo] password for rlue:
$ sudo echo \"foo\"
"foo"
```

---

#### My Specific Case

This is the command I'm trying to allow:

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo XHCI > /proc/acpi/wakeup'
```

I actually got it to work with the following unquoted command:

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL)  NOPASSWD: /bin/sh -c echo XHCI > /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

But since it calls out to `sh -c`, and since I *clearly* don't understand precisely what's going on, I'd like to be extra explicit about what I'm allowing.

**How can I specify quoting for command arguments in the sudoers file?**

Comment: Sure, but for example, `mv this that the other` is different from `mv this that 'the other'`, and the unquoted syntax permits both. How can I be sure I haven't missed any edge cases?

Answer (score 2):

edit: Warning, it appears that sudo does not safely handle spaces in the command, so it is not safe to use sudo in this way.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/279142/39281

Instead of using quotes in the sudoers file, you can escape spaces using backslash:

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL)  NOPASSWD: /bin/sh -c echo\ XHCI\ >\ /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

You can still use it as follows, because the user's shell handles the quoted argument anyway:

```
sudo /bin/sh -c 'echo XHCI > /proc/acpi/wakeup'
```

You could also consider putting a complex command into a script, as suggested in a comment.  https://serverfault.com/a/516002

Comment: This appears semantically identical to not having backslashes (that is, the arguments can still be grouped with quotation marks in every possible arrangement).

Comment: Someone commented: there's an other QA telling this is possibly unsafe: unix.stackexchange.com/questions/279125/…  then removed their comment.  But they were right, it is unsafe, seems like sudo is not safe to be used when there are spaces in the command name.  Perhaps I am misusing it, or perhaps it is a rubbish insecure tool.  If it is so easy to misuse, I suggest the latter.